# linux mv command weirdness

Tags: linux, mv

can anyone tell me why when I type:

```
mv -f ./tmp/members ./
```

I get:

```
mv: cannot move `./tmp/members' to a subdirectory of itself, `./members'
```

And moreover the correct way to move this directory?

Also, there is already a directory at ./members ... I want to completely overwrite this directory, not just add the new contents to it.

```
Directory Structure:
./
./members
./members/srno
./members/srno/expired
./members/1
./members/1/active
./members/members
./members/members/srno
./members/members/srno/expired
./members/members/1
./members/members/1/active
./members/members/57364
./members/members/57364/expired
./members/members/11939
./members/members/11939/expired
./members/members/123
./members/members/123/expired
./members/members/73331
./members/members/73331/expired
./members/members/88144
./members/members/88144/expired
./members/members/25051
./members/members/25051/expired
./members/57364
./members/57364/expired
./members/11939
./members/11939/expired
./members/123
./members/123/expired
./members/73331
./members/73331/expired
./members/88144
./members/88144/expired
./members/remove
./members/25051
./members/25051/expired
./index.html
./tmp
./tmp/members
./tmp/members/srno
./tmp/members/srno/expired
./tmp/members/1
./tmp/members/1/active
./tmp/members/57364
./tmp/members/57364/expired
./tmp/members/11939
./tmp/members/11939/expired
./tmp/members/123
./tmp/members/123/expired
./tmp/members/73331
./tmp/members/73331/expired
./tmp/members/88144
./tmp/members/88144/expired
./tmp/members/25051
./tmp/members/25051/expired
./tmp/subscribers.xml
./premium.cgi
```

Thanks!

-Eric

Comment: Is there symlinks involved?

Comment: nope, no symlinks

Comment: ok, I lied... the folder above the folder I'm working in has a symlink pointing to it... but there are no symlinks in the folder I'm moving.

Comment: [Crossposted](http://superuser.com/questions/165512/linux-mv-command-weirdness) on StackOverflow, then mod-moved to SuperUser (please don't crosspost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

`cp -rf ./tmp/members/* ./`

Following that, remove `./tmp/members` if you don't want to keep a copy.  `mv` doesn't "overwrite."

Using relative paths is a bad habit and will be something that you will easily regret.  I recommend using full paths whenever reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, but this leaves behind the old contents of ./members as well

I'm trying to do a near-instantaneous replace, as files are being served by apache from this directory.

Thanks,

 -Eric

Comment: Thanks, that is working, but still leaves behind the old directories. Best,

 -Eric

Comment: `rm -rf` the old data that you don't want.

Comment: Thanks, though that would require doing a recursive comparison between the 2...

I think my best option might be to use rsync, as it seems that mv and cp don't support this.

Comment: `cp -rf` will copy everything.  rsync's probably the better choice, I considered suggesting it but was stuck on the method.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
mv -f ./tmp/members .
```

Comment: nope, that returns the same error, but thanks for trying :-)

Comment: I've discovered that this works:

mv tmp/members members
but only for new contents... the old contents are still left behind...

Comment: That just moves the directory within the subdirectory.

Comment: @Warner: That's what I thought he wanted. The question was apparently incomplete.

Comment: Yea, I was responding to Eric's comment.  I suspected you were acting in good faith, Dennis.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer (though you already accepted another):

```
mv ./members ./.trash-members ; mv ./tmp/members ./ ; rm -rf ./.trash-members &
```

This way the old directory is removed in the background, and the new directory is put into place in very short order (the two moves should be very quick as long as you're on the same filesystem)

Also note that this solution does not use secure temporary files the way it should.